# NP-Completeness and commutative property

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, reductions

If $X$ is NP-complete and for some $Y, X\leq_p Y$ and $Y\leq_p X$ what can we say about $Y$?

My intuition says that this is only the case when $X=Y$ but I'm not sure how to justify this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your property holds for, for example 3-SAT and 3-COLOURABILITY so it's certainly not required that $X=Y$.

The fact that $Y\leq_p X$ and $X\in\mathrm{NP}$ tells you that $Y\in\mathrm{NP}$; the fact that $X$ is $\mathrm{NP}$-complete and $X\leq_p Y$ tells you that $Y$ is $\mathrm{NP}$-hard.  Therefore, $Y$ is $\mathrm{NP}$-complete.

Answer (score 2):

Since $X$ is NPC and reduces in polynomial time to $Y$, we have that $Y$ is also NPC as nicely explained in [David's answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/105827/472). Further, since $Y$ is also reducible in polynomial time to $X$, we say that $X$ and $Y$ are *polynomially equivalent*.

It is not at all true that $X$ would have to equal $Y$ in order for $X$ and $Y$ to be polynomially equivalent. You can find a good amount of examples from e.g., graph theory by just searching with this term.